# Some Philosophical Questions About Mathematics and Logic

Tags: logic, soft-question, philosophy

The following questions may seem very philosophical and I guess that you guys will tell me that this is not the right place for asking them.
But for me it is important to get answers from *mathematicians* and not from philosophers.

Note: The questions are *subjective*. I am asking for YOUR **opinion**. So if you tell me your opinion I would be very happy ;-D

1. *Is "5 is not a set" a mathematical statement?* I don't want to know, if you think it is a *true* statement, or a *false* statement, but I want to know whether you think it is a statement at all.
   In type theory, one can't express "5 is not a set". However, should a foundation for mathematics be able to express this sentence?
2. Is "second-order logic" a logic at all? Or is it just "set theory in disguise"?
3. Do we use the language of higher-order logic in ordinary mathematics? Or are we always working with first-order logic?
   Comment: Maybe you are going to say that the definition of a topological space is higher-order because we quantify over sets of sets of ... individuals. But that is not what I mean with "using higher-order logic". The example "definition of topological space" can be expressed in set theory which is a first-order theory. Thus with "using higher-order logic" I do not mean quantification over sets, which is a first-order concept, but I mean "quantification over properties".
4. Is "working in formal systems (like the predicate calculus)" mathematics? That is: Does "proving of logical tautologies" belong to mathematics?
   Is it a subfield of mathematics? Is there research in this area?

Comment: Subjective questions tend to be frowned upon here, unfortunately.

Comment: I know. But where else can I find out the opinions of MATHEMATICIANS to this philosophical questions?

Comment: Perhaps we could get away with rephrasing the question as "what are some common opinions on the underlying philosophy" or something like that.

Comment: Opinion: Yes, it is mathematics, though by no means all of mathematics.

Comment: @André: This refers to the question number 4, right?

Comment: Yes, question 4.  Although I do not think Formalism  gives an accurate description of mathematics, neither does a diametrically opposite viewpoint.

Comment: Try asking one question at a time, and things might go better ....

Comment: @Peter: I suspect that no question which bluntly asks for "your philosophical opinion" is on topic here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> For 1. : Is "5 is not a set" a mathematical statement?

Yes, of course; it is expressible in *set theory* (like $\mathsf{ZF}$) and set theory, much more than a *foundational* theory, is a *mathematical* theory.

> For 2. : Is "working in formal systems (like the predicate calculus)" mathematics?

The "mathematical part" of mathematical logic is mainly the meta-theory. In terms of mathematical knowledge, a formal derivation in predicate calculus is quite uninteresting (nor more interesting that performing a sum). But Gödel Completeness Theorem for predicate calculus is an outstanding "piece" of mathematics.